# Simple Example on how to use KevLinDev intersection

Tags: javascript

could someone give me very simple example how to use KevLinDev Class Method intersectCircleLine in javascript. Some values:

```
 circle_x = 100;
 circle_y = 100;
 radius = 200; 
 a1.x = -100;
 a1.y = -100;
 a2.x = 0; 
 a2.y = 0;
```

http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm#Anchor-intersectCircleLin-40934

I would like to know how to :

1. include intersections.js in my code.
2. How to pass above variables to function
3. How to get results?

Comment: You should post what you have done so far.

Comment: Reopen vote reason: There's really no need to close this. The question is very direct, and only needs 3 short lines to answer: _"How do I include a script file?"_, _"How do I pass parameters?"_ and _"How is the result formatted?"_

Answer (score 1):

Include these scrips:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/Intersection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/point2d/Point2D.js"></script>
```

Looking at the [source code](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/Intersection.js) for that library, something like this seem to be what you want:

```
var circle = new Point2D(circle_x, circle_y),
    point1 = new Point2D(a1.x, a1.y),
    point2 = new Point2D(a2.x, a2.y),
    intersection = Intersection.intersectCircleLine(circle, radius, point1, point2);
```

For this example:

```
var circle = new Point2D(50, 50),
    point1 = new Point2D(0, 0),
    point2 = new Point2D(100, 100),
    intersection = Intersection.intersectCircleLine(circle, 50, point1, point2);
```

`console.log(intersection)` will display:

```
{ // (Intersection Object)
    status: "Intersection", // Can also be "Inside" or "Outside".
    points: [               // If `status` is "Intersection". Otherwise, it's [].
        { // (Point2D Object)
            x: 85.35533905932738,
            y: 85.35533905932738
        },
        { // (Point2D Object)
            x: 14.644660940672624,
            y: 14.644660940672624
        }
    ]
}
```

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XKZ5m/1/)**

Comment: This gives "TypeError: a1.lerp is not a function"

Comment: @user3604005: Seems like we need another library. I added it to the answer, with a working example.