# How to find intersecting point on a circle in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, intersection

I'm trying to find intersecting point on circle. Can anybody solve this?. please find my problem's explanation image [click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fA01.png)

Comment: Could you give examples of the code you've already tried?

Comment: Do you know the radius of the circle? And do you have the svg code that creates the original image?

Comment: This is a trigonometry problem, and has nothing to do with javascript or svg.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to do the trigonometry using js/svg

Comment: Here is my svg code for my problem. any formula to find that intersect point?                                                                               <svg id="pie_svg" width="600" height="400">
<circle id='centerpoint' cx='250' cy='200' r='1' fill='blue' stroke='blue' stroke-width='1'></circle> <circle id='circlepath' cx='250' cy='200' r='100' fill='transparent' stroke='blue' stroke-width='1'></circle><line x1="250" y1="200" x2="370" y2="270" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<line x1="370" y1="270" x2="170" y2="270" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" /></svg>

Comment: I need to place text element on intersected point

Comment: It's simple, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23470952/6224820

Comment: @BhuvaneshValarmaan Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have the radius of the circle, as well as the center point of the circle. If you do, then the coordinates of the respective points are as follows:

```
// assume r is set to the radius of the circle
// and (x, y) is the center of the circle
p1.x = x - r * Math.sin(Math.acos(150 / r));
p1.y = y + 150;
p2.x = x + r * Math.sin(Math.acos(150 / r));
p2.y = y + 150;
```